# UWP: Slow SVG Image Load in Gridview

Tags: image, performance, svg, gridview, uwp

I want to load multiple SVG images in Gridview of my UWP app. But every time after app launch, it takes some time to show those images and the area for this time being remains blank which is not user friendly. But if I use png images, it performs normally. There are total 9 items in this gridview, so total  9*2=18 svg images(each 55 kb). Can anyone suggest, how to load these svg images faster in uwp?

```
            <GridView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" 
                      IsItemClickEnabled="True">
               
                <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                             <Image Source="{Binding Normal,Mode=OneWay}" Visibility="{Binding NormalVisibility, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                             <Image Source="{Binding Selected, Mode=OneWay}" Visibility="{Binding SelectedVisibility, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridView.ItemTemplate>

            </GridView>
```

Comment: When I loaded the SVG files, it didn't take much time to display, may I know how you defined and handled the Normal property? Can you provide a simple sample that can be reproduced for us to test?

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT Here is my code:
 `Items = new ObservableCollection<Dummy>();` ------`for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++){Items.Add(new Dummy { Normal = Normal_Path[i], Selected = Selected_Path[i]});}` ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    `public class Dummy : MVVMBase
    {
        public string Normal { get; set; }
        public string elected { get; set; }
     }`

Comment: Is your Normal property pointing to the SVG path? Can you provide the svg image and a simple sample that can be reproduced for us to test?